# Caliburn.Micro Xamarin Tutorials

Tags: xamarin, caliburn.micro

I am looking into using Caliburn.Micro in a Xamarin Android and iOS Native project.

Caliburn.Micro for Xamarin seems relatively new (correct me if I am wrong) and there doesn't appear to be any Caliburn.Micro Xamarin tutorials. Does anyone know of any Caliburn.Micro Xamarin tutorials?

I am hoping the developers of the Caliburn.Micro Xamarin 'fork' will see this and suggest some of they exist or create some if they dont.

There are example projects such as [here](https://github.com/nigel-sampson/xamarin-experiments) and in the Caliburn.Micro Github but tutorials are invaluable.

Comment: take into account that it only went beta-1 with in the last 6 days.  There are still some pretty length items to check off for the Xamarin side of the release.

Comment: As of writing this the tutorials haven't been written, the best reference at the moment is the samples Hello.Xamarin and Hello.Forms on the 3.0.0 branch.

Comment: @NigelSampson We don't need tutorials. We just need a serious Xamarin.Forms project sample, that display ALL features and functionalities, shown in a simple way, each one separatedly (not all mixed together!), and with clear and commented code.